# Get page content on idle wait timeout in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

Puppeteer's `page.goto()` method has a `timeout` property of [options](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.goto#remarks) argument, which is the maximum navigation time in milliseconds for cases when the source is unresponsive, unreachable or fails to load, but is there a timeout option, other method or approach to still return the response in case the `waitUntil` options (load, networkidle0, networkidle2 etc.) exceed a given time in milliseconds?

For example, a `TimeoutError` exception will be thrown in this code, if the response takes longer than the given `timeout`, but it will also timeout if the `networkidle0` condition is not met within the given timeout.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const url = 'https://httpbin.org/delay/10';

  try {
    const res = await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      timeout: 3000, // 3 seconds of navigation timeout
    });

    console.log(await res.status(), await page.content());
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I want to avoid the exception and get `status` and `content` if response is valid but `networkidle0` condition couldn't be met within a given time (same or different to the navigation `timeout`). Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use my custom waiter for network idle from puppeteer wrapper library.

https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai

[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/classes/src.networkdriver.html#waitfornetworkidle)

Also you can choose request types you want to not to happen during some time interval.

```js
import { waitForNetworkIdle } from 'bubanai-ng';

...

 const res = await page.goto(url, {
      timeout: 3000, // 3 seconds of navigation timeout
    });
    await new NetworkDriver(page).waitForNetworkIdle();
```

Comment: I notice you've posted many answers that basically self-promote your wrapper library. You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior: "If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons".

Comment: Large? Can you please share what do you mean "many" in percentage equivalent? 
If ~ 4-5 posts that solves real problems with my library from annual ~ 110 is 'many' and looks like self-promotion, so I don't know anything about self-promotion.

Comment: You've posted 31 answers in [tag:puppeteer], 10 of which promote your lib. All of them were posted in the past month, in some cases 2-3 in a day, as on July 1st. So the numbers you quote are misleading--you're on track for 120 posts per year promoting your library, if we start counting from July 1st. Based on your upvote and acceptance rate (1 upvote out of 10 promo posts) and my being SME in Puppeteer, I don't think they're solving real problems or I wouldn't be bothering you about it.

Comment: Your calculation is not correct. You counting % of topic mentions and not % of all answers. 
Also, you rely on upvotes and not rely on real SR of my solution. "Does my code solves issue or not". Most of the issues I solved there were not upvoted / commented, most of authors just disappeared. I can make a conclusion that they are not upvoted, because usually you try not to rely on open-source libs. And that's ok.
Also, you have small amount of data to predict number 120. 
Promoting library it's not point of my being there. But I would be glad if someone would improve SR, using my experience.

Comment: I don't see the point in counting answers where your library isn't applicable to the question because there's zero possibility for promoting it. But if you want to choose metrics that favor your position, OK, 8% of all of your answers are self-promo, and that's without looking at any of your non-Puppeteer answers--I wouldn't be surprised if there were spammy self-promo posts among those for other libraries of yours.

Comment: Yes, there's not much data, because you've only been answering on the site for a month. But the results are not looking good--I haven't seen a single high-quality answer yet.

Comment: I invite you to check my other answers and to verify proposed solutions. If my code works as asker expected, can be that answer considered as 'spam'?

Comment: Which of your promo posts was accepted? I don't see any. Also, hapless OPs accept answers occasionally randomly, so the presence of one doesn't prove much. Anyway, I'm not really interested in arguing, I'm interested in informing you. You can take what I say into consideration or not, but your arguments aren't going to change my opinion of your current set of answers.